# Array issue using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, readline

I am currently working on a simple product machine using node/terminal and i have run into a problem. I have added an array with number ID's relating to the element. And i am using readline to ask what product the user would like.

When entering ID 1 it provides the successful message for a drink. But when entering 2, 3 or 4. Nothing happens?

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong here, i would really appreciate it!

Kind Regards!

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync'),
products = [];
products[1] = "Drink";
products[2] = "Crisps";
products[3] = "Chocolate";
products[4] = "Candy";

var productPurchase = readlineSync.question('Would you like to purchase a   product? ');
if (productPurchase == "yes") {
    index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(products, 'What product would you like?');
if (index == [1]) {
    console.log('Thank you, your Drink' + ' has now been dispensed.');
if (index == [2]) {
    console.log('Thank you, your Crisps' + ' has now been dispensed.');
if (index == [3]) {
    console.log('Thank you, your Chocolate' + ' has now been dispensed.');
if (index == [4]) {
    console.log('Thank you, your Candy' + ' has now been dispensed.');

}}}}}
```

Comment: It looks like you want `if( index[0] === 1 )` and so on.

Comment: Why so much downvotes on all answers?

Comment: @RGraham please explain.

Comment: @Dropout. In your answer, why do you compare `index` to different arrays?

Comment: @Dropout Know what, I'll admit when I made a mistake. I assumed the OP was using strict equality and hence downvoted the questions comparing `1 == [1]`. My bad

Comment: @Marc I've changed it to numbers, the main point is the nesting of the ifs though..

Answer (score 5):

Your nested `if`'s will never be executed, `index` cannot both be 1 and 3 at the same time. I would suggest you use a `switch` instead, it is basically what you are trying to do :

```
var productPurchase = readlineSync.question('Would you like to purchase a   product? ');
if (productPurchase == "yes") {
    index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(products, 'What product would you like?');
    switch (index) {
      case 1 : 
        console.log('Thank you, your Drink' + ' has now been dispensed.');
        break;
      case 2 :  
        console.log('Thank you, your Crisps' + ' has now been dispensed.');
        break;
      case 3 :
        console.log('Thank you, your Chocolate' + ' has now been dispensed.');
        break;
      case 4 :   
        console.log('Thank you, your Candy' + ' has now been dispensed.');
        break;
      default :
        console.log('something went wrong'); 
        break;
    }
}
```

NB : Have corrected the wrong usage of `index`. [**`keyInSelect()`**](https://github.com/anseki/readline-sync#utility_methods-keyinselect) returns the index as a number, not as an array.

Comment: Why not drop the `switch` and replace it with `console.log('Thank you, your ' + products[index] + ' has now been dispensed.');`

Comment: Thanks i will look into using switch in this case then! :)

Comment: This answer is correct. It is also a good idea to get rid of "==" and use only "===" in your statements as JavaScript non-strict comparison operator "==" often displayes unpredictable behaviour. It will work here correctly but it's bad practice.

Comment: @ZenoX Can you mark one of the answers as accepted, so everyone knows your problem has been solved?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync'),
products = [];
products[1] = "Drink";
products[2] = "Crisps";
products[3] = "Chocolate";
products[4] = "Candy";

var productPurchase = readlineSync.question('Would you like to purchase a   product? ');
if (productPurchase == "yes") {
    index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(products, 'What product would you like?');
    if (index == [1]) 
        console.log('Thank you, your Drink' + ' has now been dispensed.');
    else if (index == [2]) 
        console.log('Thank you, your Crisps' + ' has now been dispensed.');
    else if (index == [3]) 
        console.log('Thank you, your Chocolate' + ' has now been dispensed.');
    else if (index == [4]) 
        console.log('Thank you, your Candy' + ' has now been dispensed.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

You are nesting your `if` statements. Set them on the same level. Optionally, also use `if else`:

```
if (index == 1) {
  console.log('Thank you, your Drink' + ' has now been dispensed.');
}
else if (index == 2) {
  console.log('Thank you, your Crisps' + ' has now been dispensed.');
}
else if (index == 3) {
  console.log('Thank you, your Chocolate' + ' has now been dispensed.');
}
else if (index == 4) {
  console.log('Thank you, your Candy' + ' has now been dispensed.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

Your curly braces are messed up. You have them one in another like this:

```
if(){
    if(){
        if(){
            if(){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try changing your code to:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync'),
products = [];
products[1] = "Drink";
products[2] = "Crisps";
products[3] = "Chocolate";
products[4] = "Candy";

var productPurchase = readlineSync.question('Would you like to purchase a   product? ');
if (productPurchase == "yes") {
    index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(products, 'What product would you like?');
    if (index == 1) {
        console.log('Thank you, your Drink' + ' has now been dispensed.');
    }
    if (index == 2) {
        console.log('Thank you, your Crisps' + ' has now been dispensed.');
    }
    if (index == 3) {
        console.log('Thank you, your Chocolate' + ' has now been dispensed.');
    }
    if (index == 4) {
        console.log('Thank you, your Candy' + ' has now been dispensed.');
    }

}
```

Using correct indentation helps avoid problems such as this. If your code was written more cleanly you would notice the problem right away probably.

Note: You might want to change these `if` statements into a `switch`. This is a situation in which it would be probably best.

Comment: Thanks i will look into using switch in this case then! :)